# Exception while getting a certificate

Tags: c#

I am getting an unhandled exception, when I try to use `First` in the below line of code.

```
X509Certificate2 cert = store.Certificates.Cast<X509Certificate2>()
                                          .First(item => item.FriendlyName =="myfriendlyname");
```

I even tried `FirstOrDefault`,`Single` and `SingleOrDefault` and got the

> Unhandled Exception System.ApplicationNullException: value cannot be
>   null.

Kindly help me resolve the same.

Comment: Have you tried debugging? Are you certain `FriendlyName` isn't NULL for any of the `item`s?

Comment: Did you check if one of the certificates is null?

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
X509Certificate2 cert = store.Certificates.Cast<X509Certificate2>().Where(item => item.FriendlyName =="myfriendlyname").FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: FirstOrDefault could accept also a boolean condition removing the need of WHERE

Answer (score -1):

When you try to access the first element of the query, if it doesn't exist the exception is thrown. You should modify your code and use FirstOrDefault method. When result of the query is empty the result will be null. Then you can verify whether result is or is not empty.

```
var cert = store.Certificates.Cast<X509Certificate2>().Where(item => item.FriendlyName =="myfriendlyname").FirstOrDefault();
if(cert != null)
{
   sth;
}
```

Comment: FirstOrDefault could accept also a boolean condition removing the need of WHERE

Comment: @Steve Thank you Steve I thought about it but wasn't sure.

Comment: @NishaP Have it helped you? Was it cause of your problem or it's something else?